# Finding number of digits in integer when being passed an int = 0

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers, digits, logarithm

Using Java btw. But Usually people seem to do this sort of thing with.

```
int numDigits = (int)(log10(num)+1); //can explicitly floor, or casting to int will do that
```

but log10(0) = -INF, which means my length is being set to the largest negative integer value.

I suppose I could make a condition

```
if (numDigits is negative)
    numDigits = 1 //not 0 because I'm counting 0 as 1 digit.
```

This is being used to implement a natural number constructor, just so people have context to my problem.

Comment: What is the question? You could also do `numDigits= (num==0?1:(int)(log10(num)+1))`

Comment: Can't you simply parse int to string and get its length?

Comment: @FrancisP: It is a terrible solution if this is done in a tight loop, it will take much longer I believe to construct the string then a simple log

Comment: @amit what exactly does the (num==0?1:(int)... part do?

Comment: @amit: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306727/way-to-get-number-of-digits-in-an-int

Comment: @Aerlusch: It is the trenary operator, you need to take only the special case of `num == 0`, if it is - no need to even take the log - the answer is 1.

Comment: this needs to also ignore leading zeros, so if the incoming type is int then 000 is the same as 0, correct?

Comment: I think the 0 case has to be handled separately using log, both because of the -INF problem, and because it is the only case in which a leading zero is counted as a digit. If this is in a performance critical situation I would measure both this calculation and Integer.toString(num).length(). It is not obvious to me that the log10 calculation will necessarily be faster, and the string approach requires no special cases.

Comment: Test against http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog10 methods that don't require a round trip to float and back. This may be a stupid question, but what is a "natural number constructor"?

Comment: @A.Webb a constructor for a Natural number class. It basically represents a natural number and the size of the number is only limited by the memory of the JVM. When declaring a new object for my class you initialize it with a non-negative integer value. This value is defaulted to 0 if nothing is passed, or it can read it na integer, String, or an Object of my natural number class. I was just having issues when 0 was passed in as an integer.

Comment: @Aerlush So, you are reimplementing Bignum?

Answer (score 0):

The code you listed would mean that -10 has a numDigits value of 1 which I believe is incorrect.

How about converting the number to string and getting the string length?

Comment: `log10(10) + 1 = 1+1 = 2` :|

Comment: Its an implementation of a natural number class. It requires input to be a positive integer, or a string representing a positive integer, or can take be initialised with an object of its own type. Anyways the requires prevents negative numbers from being an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a particular optimization problem, then go for the log solution:

```
int length = (number ==0) ? 1 : (int)Math.log10(number) + 1;
```

Else, I recommand you use the String.valueOf solution, since it is much more readable and easier to understand for future developpers/maintainers:

```
int length = String.valueOf(number).length();
```

Comment: This is assuming `number` is an `int`... So `0000` would be considered as `0`.

Comment: i think that stringSize() method in Integer class would be faster than log10 method

Comment: @guido: But the construction of the string object itself won't be.