# Fastest way to get number of digits on a number?

Tags: java, string, math, numbers, int

I have do detect the amount of digits on a number. For example, `329586` has `6` digits.

What I done, is simply parsing the number to string, and getting the string length, like:

```
number.toString().length()
```

But, is there a fastest way to count digits on a number? I have to use this method several times, so I think using `toString()` can impact performance.

Thanks.

Comment: by number you mean an integer ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
Math.floor(Math.log10(number) + 1)
// or just (int) Math.log10(number) + 1
```

For example:

```
int number = 123456;
int length = (int) Math.log10(number) + 1;
System.out.println(length);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
6
```

Comment: That's not the fastest way, see the this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306727/way-to-get-number-of-digits-in-an-int/1308407#1308407

Comment: This method needs the number==0 case to be handled separately.

Comment: Yes, this does **not** work for zero!

Comment: Although not the fastest or most general solution, it is very elegant!

Answer (score 13):

how about this homebrewed solution:

```
int noOfDigit = 1;
while((n=n/10) != 0) ++noOfDigit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

[Working Example](http://ideone.com/VP9uPT)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long num = -23;
        int digits = 0;
        if (num < 0) 
            num *= (-1);
        if (num < 10 && num >= 0)
            digits = 1;
        else {
            while(num > 0) {
                num /= 10;
                digits++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Digits: " +digits);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you too! :D But, just saying, it won't work for 0 and 1...

Comment: Now it will work for 0, 1 and also for negative numbers.

Comment: for 10, it would return 1!

Comment: Sorry. Updated my answer.