# Logarithm-based solution calculates incorrect number of digits in large integers

Tags: java, math, numbers

I don't have enough reputation points yet to leave comments, but saw numerous times when people (incorrectly) suggest using log10 to calculate the number of digits in a positive integer. This is wrong for large numbers!

```
long n = 99999999999999999L;

// correct answer: 17
int numberOfDigits = String.valueOf(n).length();

// incorrect answer: 18
int wrongNumberOfDigits = (int) (Math.log10(n) + 1); 
// also incorrect:
double wrongNumberOfDigits2 = Math.floor(Math.log10(n) + 1);
```

The logarithm-based solutions will incorrectly output 18 instead of 17.

I'd like to understand why.

[Way to get number of digits in an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306727/way-to-get-number-of-digits-in-an-int)
[Fastest way to get number of digits on a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587818/fastest-way-to-get-number-of-digits-on-a-number)

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: I'd like to understand why it's incorrect for large numbers, and also would like to bring awareness about this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `99999999999999999` cannot be exactly represented as a (double precision) floating-point value in this case. The nearest value is `1.0E+17` when passed as a `double` parameter to `log10`.

The same would be true of the `log10(n)` value: `16.999999999999999995657...` - the nearest value that can be represented is `17`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I wonder what the biggest long integer is where the logarithm-based solution will be correct?

Comment: @moodcheerful - what you really want to ask is: what is the *range* of contiguous integer values that can be exactly represented? There's a good answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double).

Answer (score 1):

It is **mathematically absolutely** correct.

**Number of digit of any integer not null (positive !) is log10(n)+1. No doubt !**

Problems arise with representations, as pointed by Brett Hale.

So, if you want, no problem, no limit, very accurate calculation :)  **use BigDecimal.**

**But simplest: use lengthof String:**

```
Long l=99999999999999999L;
int len=l.toString().length();
```

If you *really* want to do calculation, see

that: [Logarithm of a BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739532/logarithm-of-a-bigdecimal)

that: [BigDecimal to the power of BigDecimal on Java/Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848887/bigdecimal-to-the-power-of-bigdecimal-on-java-android/22556217#22556217)