# How can I allocate memory for an array of digits (int) of a number with the length being equal to the number of digits of that number?

Tags: java, arrays, int

e.g. for `int n = 1234` I could create a string `(s.valueOf(n))`, then I would define the array like this:

```
int[] array = new int[s.length()]; //this allocates memory for an array with 4 elements
```

Is there any other way to do this **without using a string** and only integers?

Comment: Sorry? Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Getting the length in digits of a number is a well known problem for programming students. I am sure you can google it pretty quickly.

Comment: @freak - What else can I say?

Comment: @freak he basically wants to get the size of n and initialize his array. like int n= 1234; here you have 4 digits, thus length would be 4

Comment: int is primitive and I think doesn't have a method for finding its length

Comment: @constant you should say like PermGenError elaborate it.

Comment: Yes, you could write yourself a little method to work this out without using Strings, but is this a homework task? Don't want to just go giving you the answer without you showing us what you've tried first.

Comment: Good, I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306727/way-to-get-number-of-digits-in-an-int

Comment: Just simple mathematics, you need the concept of logarithm. As the given answer suggests.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [Math#log10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10%28double%29) to find the number of digits.

```
numOfDigits = (int)(Math.log10(n)+1);
```

Now you do:

```
int[] array = new int[numOfDigits];
```

Note that if `n = 1999`, `numOfDigits` will be 4. So you're allocating a memory for 4 integers and not 1999 integers.

But be careful, while reading the documentation of the method, you'll note:

> If the argument is positive zero or negative zero, then the result is
>   negative infinity.

Comment: Log is a bit overkill, if you need an integer upper approximation in the end.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are talking about Java, so:

```
 int value = myValue;
 for (int noOfDigits = 1; Math.abs(value) >= 1; ++noOfDigits) {
     value /= 10;
 }

 int[] array = new int[noOfDigits];
```

This does not include space for the leading sign if the number is negative, but you can easily test this condition and increment `noOfDigits` by one.

Answer (score 2):

Use `log function` to find the no. of digits.

```
int size = (int)Math.log10(1234)+1;
int[] array = new int[size];
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding you can do the following to get count of digits

```
    int n = 12345;
    int count = 1;
    while(n>10){
         n = n/10;
         count++; 
    }
    int[] array = new int[count];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (n>0){
    numberOfDigets = (int)(Math.log10(n)+1);
} 
else if (n < 0){
    numberOfDigets = (int)(Math.log10(Math.abs(n))+1);
} else {
    numberOfDigets = 1;
}
```

If n is bigger then zero use the Math.log10 function as Maroun Maroun wrote. If the n is less the zero use the Math.abs function to get a positiv value. If you want to allocate space for the - the add 2 instead of 1. The else clause is for the case when n is zero and sets numberOfDigets to 1.

If an extra call to a java function don't matter use this code.
    if (n != 0){
        numberOfDigets = (int)(Math.log10(Math.abs(n))+1);
    } else {
        numberOfDigets = 1;
    }

`Math.abs(n)` will always return a positiv version of n. The value to watch out for is the `Integer.min_value` beacuse that value will still be negativ, but that is another question.