# How to calculate the no. of digits of a number in java?

Tags: java

Is there any single line of code that can be used to calculate the number of digits in a program? I mean to say, can be there a reference to a class (such as String.length for a String) which can be used to calculate the number of digits in a number?

Comment: cast int to string and use this methog

Comment: Do you have the value as a number (int, long, double, char) or as a String?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306727/way-to-get-number-of-digits-in-an-int

Comment: Which type of number - there any many: integer, float, short, double, decimal...

Comment: no need for valueOf() despite most of the answers, ("" + number) is a string.

Comment: I need to calculate the length of an Integer Number.

Comment: Or is there any line of code to parse an Integer into a String?

Comment: concatenate the integer to the end of an empty string: ("" + number)

Comment: Just one last Question, is there a Syntax like (Integer. ...)

Comment: This question was closed for the wrong reason: it's clear what this question is asking, and it's actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306727/way-to-get-number-of-digits-in-an-int.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to avoid converting to a `String` (and convert to a `double` and back to an `int` instead):

```
digits = int(Math.log10(a)) + 1;
```

If you also need to handle negative numbers:

```
digits = int(Math.log10(Math.abs(a))) + 1;
// uncomment the following line to count the negative sign as a digit
// if (a < 0) { digits += 1; }
```

Comment: +1, as the log approach is about 20 times faster than the string conversion one.

Comment: You need special handling in case `a` is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int len = ("" + number).length();
```

Comment: I think this is a nice solution and a bit overlooked :)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Math.floor(Math.log10(num)) + 1
```

for integers. Use

```
String.valueOf(num).length()
```

for anything else

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 125846;
System.out.println("Length is "+String.valueOf(a).length());
```

Output:

```
Length is 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int bubba = 56733;
System.out.println(String.valueOf(bubba).length());
```

Output: 5

Answer (score 0):

You could always do something like String.valueOf(

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer.toString(19991).length();
```

Comment: I copied this code on my blueJ, and it doesn't compile.

Comment: The method is called `toString()`. Remember that Java convention is that method starts with lowercase, classes with uppercase.

Comment: typo, sorry.  Updated.