# What would be the SQL query/command to find length of numeric field from a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, database-administration

I want to know how we can find of length of Numeric field in sql. What will be the command / Query so that we can find length of perticular field in table.

E.g.:
For below table:

```
Column1 Column2
1          1111  
2            11
3         44444      
4            11
5           111
```

From above example I want to see Record/fields in column "column2" which has numeric length '2'.

What query should I execute to achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand your definition of numeric length

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEN` function

```
select * 
from table 
where len(column2) = 2
```

This will not work when you want to include data like '0.2' or similar values

Comment: Thank you for the quick help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `POWER` function and `<` and `>=` to maintain SARGability

```
WITH tbl (column1, column2) AS(
    SELECT 1, 1111 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 11 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 44444 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 11 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 111
)
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE
    column2 < POWER(10, 2)
    AND column2 >= POWER(10, 1)
```

Comment: I believe this will include `10.2` which is not of length 2 but for the given data this is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306727/way-to-get-number-of-digits-in-an-int)

> Length and digits are both properties of a physical representation of a number in a specific base, i.e. a String.

So you have to convert numeric field to varchar/char first then find the length as follows:

**SQL Server:**

```
select * 
from table 
where len(CONVERT (varchar(10), colunm2 )) = 2
```

**MySQL:**

```
select * 
from table 
where length(convert(column2,char)) = 2
```