# Java, how to get Chronometer

Tags: java

I was following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306727/way-to-get-number-of-digits-in-an-int) there's a code which uses `Chronometer` , however i cant find where this is? do i need to import some library or package for this ?
form this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/jdev/api-reference-esdk/oracle/javatools/util/Chronometer.html) it seems to be in `oracle.javatools.util.Chronometer` , but how to get it ?

auto import cant resolve it

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle docs

```
public final class Chronometer
extends java.lang.Object
```

This class implements a virtual digital stopwatch (or chronometer), providing basic and useful functionalities for time measurement, such as start(), stop(), multiple laps and total elapsed running time.

You need to import package

```
oracle.javatools.util.Chronometer
```

in your class file and also make sure Oracle Extension SDK jars are in your classpath.

Comment: how to get or include Oracle Extension SDK jars ?

Answer (score 1):

That class appears to be part of the Oracle Fusion Middleware, as part of the Oracle Extension SDK: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/index-091862.html

API: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/jdev/api-reference-esdk/oracle/javatools/util/Chronometer.html

As a general rule, if you're trying to find which jars contain a particular class, use http://www.findjar.com/