# Do-While loop user-entered not looping

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

```
int ID;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
ID = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

do{
   System.out.println("Improper EMPID, please reenter your EMPID.\n");
   Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
   ID = Integer.parseInt(scan1.nextLine());
}
while (ID > 999999 && ID < 10000000);

return ID;
```

This is a function in my main code where I attempt to have the user enter a seven digit ID. 
 It's supposed to **loop infinitely until the user enters seven digits**, however will only loop through once then exits.  
 
 I have also done this with a while loop with the same results.  Something I'm not seeing here?

```
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  int id = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

  while (id >= 10000000 || id <= 999999);{
     System.out.println("Please enter your EMPID\n");
     id = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
  }


  return id;
```

My code now looks like this.

It will constantly loop without showing the print.

Comment: You are checking the values in the loop condition, not the amount of digits! The loop never gets entered because there is no number (-value) between 999999 and 1000000 that can be stored as `int` or `Integer`. Have a look at [this question about the amount of digits of an `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306727/way-to-get-number-of-digits-in-an-int). You can check the value, but then only check if it is less than 10000000 to make it less than 7 digits.

Comment: And you don’t need a new scanner each time

Comment: deHaar, how would I be able to do that?  Also I just realized it wont work as a do-while loop, so I have changed it back to a while loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should continue the loop when the input is invalid:

```
while (ID <= 999999 || ID >= 10000000);
```

---

Not related to the question, but please name variables with camel case, and remove unecessary code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int id = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

while (id <= 999999 || id >= 10000000) {
    System.out.println("Improper EMPID, please reenter your EMPID.\n");
    id = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: I changed my code to how yours looks, however it now constantly loops and doesn't print the text.

Comment: @ChristopherRoskind What did you input and what's your code now?

Comment: I input the number 69152133. I will update my question with how my code currently looks.

Comment: @ChristopherRoskind You need remove the `;` in this line `while (id >= 10000000 || id <= 999999);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't check the lenght of the input, you check for the real value.
You can use `int length = String.valueOf(ID).lenght();` to get the lenght of an int value.
Just a hint: Don't create new scanners each time, you will confuse your self. One is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

this logic would be better with a while loop since you first ask the user for a value and want to give them an error message only if it's wrong

such as

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 int ID = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
 while (!ID || ID <= 999999 || ID >= 10000000) {
    System.out.println("Improper EMPID, please reenter your EMPID.\n");
    ID = Integer.parseInt(scan1.nextLine());
}
```